# Change Background when part of it is hovered

Tags: javascript, css, background, hover

i am totally new in web design, and i am right now struggling with creating part of my website, i need to somehow make this happen:

When **PART** of the **BODY BACKGROUND** is HOVERED, make the background change to "B", and when the mouse is not over that part, I need it to change back to background "A".

I have seen some examples here but as i am a beginner, i have no idea how to use javascript, if you could please give me some light here, either on pure CSS or on how to apply javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished very easily using a third party javascript library called JQuery http://jquery.com, you can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bbp8G/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hover").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background","#009900");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background","#ffffff"); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Of course, this code changes the element's background, not the BODY's background.  See my answer

Comment: The thing is: i need it to change the background when only PART of the background is hovered, not any part...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way I know how to do what you've described...

```
<!-- POSITION THIS DIV WHEREVER YOU WANT THE 
USER TO HOVER SO THAT THE BACKGROUND WILL CHANGE -->
<div id="hover">
</div>

<!-- PUT THIS CODE IN YOUR <HEAD> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" />
<style>
  #hover { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative; top: 200px; background: green; }
  .myNewBackround { background-color: red; }
</style>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // when the #hover DIV is hovered, change the background of the body
    $('#hover').hover(function() {
      $('body').addClass('myNewBackground');
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Here's a JS FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKaJn/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with pure CSS

```
<div id="left">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="right">&nbsp;</div>
```

And the CSS part:

```
#left
{
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
}
#right
{
    background-color:#FF0;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
}

#right:hover
{
    background-color:#00F;    
}

#left:hover
{
    background-color:#F00;    
}
```

You can replace the div's and values with whatever you like, the main part is the #right:hover and #left:hover

Comment: Liane, i would rather use pure CSS but i dont see how **one element** is changing **another**...
i am sorry to bother but would you mind explaining?

Answer (score 0):

Actually with just css it is not possible to change the background of the *body* when hovering a DOM element. This is because CSS does not allow you (yet) to travel up the DOM tree (select a parent), only down (select a child).

That being said, it is however possible to mimic the effect, and it is even quiet easy if it is the body background you want to change. You can lay a pseudo element with a background on top of your body background, and underneath the actual content. This way it looks as if the body background has changed.

The css to achieve this would look something like this:

```
.hover-me:hover:after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/600/300) center center;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

And a small fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/3dwzt/

Should be compatible with IE8 and up